# FastAPI - Set the url or path for the Request object

Tags: python, fastapi, setattr, starlette

I have a function that looks like this:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def process_api_event(request: Request, call_next):
     url = request.url
     path = request.url.path 
     # request.__setattr__('url', 'sample_url')
     # request.url.__ setattr__('path', 'sample_path')
```

In the above function, depending on the situation I would like to change the request url, or path.
I tried `request.__setattr__('url', 'sample_url')` and `request.url.__ setattr__('path', 'sample_path')` as shown above but I wasn't able to do it due to `AttributeError: can't set attribute error`. I read through the FastAPI and Starlette documentation, but couldn't really find info that I needed in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to change the ***`url`*** attribute?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`request.url`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/requests.py#L80) is a property that gets `_url` attribute, so you can set `_url` (but `request.scope` and `request.base_url` will not change)

```
from starlette.datastructures import URL

@app.middleware("http")
async def process_api_event(request: Request, call_next):
    request._url = URL('sample_url')
    print(request.url)
    ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work, doesn't change unfortunately,